# Stream Urls for Android

Tags: url, stream

Hy guys, i'm searching for the radio stream urls to put in my Radio Player. Someone know where  i can find the stream links ? For example the stream url for BBC Radio 1, 2, 3 ... and so on.
If you know a site or something please post it here.

Comment: see this post from the tunein blog : http://blog.tunein.com/moderator-help/stations/acquiring-internet-streams

Comment: Thanks, but i can't get it working... do you know other way ?